# What is rescaling kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

When I was reading the *Sub-Bergman Hilbert spaces* (doi:10.1016/j.jmaa.2005.12.035), written by Saida Sultanic, I noticed that in page 641, he mentioned:

> Before we continue our analysis of these spaces, we will recall the definition of rescaling kernels. Let $k$ and $j$ be kernel functions for Hilbert function spaces $\mathcal{H}_k$ and $\mathcal{H}_j$, respectively. We say that $j$ is obtained from $k$ by rescaling or renormalizing if there is a nowhere vanishing function $δ$ so that
> $$
> j(ζ,λ) = \overline{δ(ζ)}δ(λ)k(ζ,λ).
> $$

But I have checked all the books I could find related with reproducing kernel, only to find nothing about `rescaling kernel` index.

I wonder what it is exactly. Does `rescaling kernel` have other more formal names that I can find on the book?

Comment: The key word seems to be "multiplier" (see for example the textbook of Paulsen and Raghupathi). If you look at the multiplier hilbert space $\delta \mathcal H$, the new reproducing kernel is given by the expression you have; conjugation by the multiplier

Comment: @operatorerror thanks so much! I’ve checked it on the book and it seems to be what I want.